# Isabelle - exI and refl behavior explanation needed

Tags: isabelle, theorem-proving

I am trying to understand the lemma below.

- Why is the `?y2` schematic variable introduced in `exI`?
- And why it is not considered in `refl` (so: `x = x`)?

> ```
> lemma "∀x. ∃y. x = y"   
>   apply(rule allI)     (*  ⋀x.      ∃y. x = y *)
>   thm exI              (*  ?P ?x ⟹ ∃x. ?P x  *)
>   apply(rule exI)      (*  ⋀x. x = ?y2 x      *)
>   thm refl             (*  ?t = ?t            *)   
>   apply(rule refl)   
> done
> ```

---

**UPDATE** (because I can't format code in comments):

This is the same lemma with a different proof, using `simp`.

> ```
> lemma "∀x. ∃y. x = y"
>   using [[simp_trace, simp_trace_depth_limit = 20]]
>   apply (rule allI)  (*So that we start from the same problem state. *)   
>   apply (simp only:exI) 
> done
> ```

The trace shows:

> ```
> [0]Adding rewrite rule "HOL.exI":
> ?P1 ?x1 ⟹ ∃x. ?P1 x ≡ True 
> [1]SIMPLIFIER INVOKED ON THE FOLLOWING TERM:
> ⋀x. ∃y. x = y 
> [1]Applying instance of rewrite rule "HOL.exI":
> ?P1 ?x1 ⟹ ∃x. ?P1 x ≡ True    
> [1]Trying to rewrite:
> x = ?x1 ⟹ ∃xa. x = xa ≡ True   <-- NOTE: not ?y2 xa or similar!
> [2]SIMPLIFIER INVOKED ON THE FOLLOWING TERM:
> x = ?x1 
> [1]SUCCEEDED
> ∃xa. x = xa ≡ True
> ```

So apparently `simp` and `rule` handles `exI` differently. And the remaining question is: what is the mechanical (programmatical) reasoning behind `rule`'s behavior.

Comment: If the answer helped you, please accept it. If not: what is missing?

Comment: @LarsNoschinski: The answer is great, my knowledge is inferior. I am catching up with a lot of information here and studying materials (literally: hundreds of pages on Isabelle and logic) - and I have a job as well ;-).

Comment: My suggestion would be to just use the system to prove interesting things without worrying too much about its internals for some time. It's more fun and you will probably find it easier to understand the internals after you've played around with the system for a while.

Comment: Yeah, that is the plan - it is just at the time I see something I don't understand I do not even know whether I am just lacking something trivial or not. So that is why I asked. I have no plans going deep under for awhile. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `rule thm` for some fact `thm`, Isabelle performs higher-order unification of the conclusion of `thm` with the current goal. If there is a unifier, it is used to instantiate both the goal and the conclusion of the theorem, and then resolution is performed (i.e. the goal is replaced with the assumptions of `thm`).

This means that:

1. Schematic variables in the goal can be instantiated by `rule` through  unification
2. Variables that appear only in the assumptions of `thm` will not be instantiated by the unification and will therefore remain schematic. That way, you end up with schematic variables in your new goals. Such variables can be seen as *existential* in some sense, because the conclusion of `thm` holds if you can prove the assumptions for just *one* arbitrary value.

In the case of `exI`, you have `?P ?x ⟹ ∃x. ?P x`. When you apply `rule exI`, the variable `?P` is instantiated to `λy. x = y`, but the variable `?x` appears only in the assumptions of `exI`, so it remains schematic. This means that you can pick any value you want for `?x` later on in your proof.

To be more precise, you end up with `⋀x. x = ?y2 x` as your goal. You might ask ‘Why not just `⋀x. x = ?y2`?’ That would mean that you have to show that `x` equals some fixed value `y2` for *all* possible values of `x`. That is obviously not true in general. `⋀x. x = ?y2 x` means you have to show that every `x` equals some `y2` that may depend on `x` – or, equivalently, that there is a function `y2` that, when given `x`, outputs `x`.

Of course, there *is* such a function and it is simply the identity function `λx. x`. That is precisely what `?y2` gets instantiated to when you apply `rule refl`: the goal `x = ?y2 x` is unified with the conclusion of refl `?t = ?t` and you end up with `?t = x` and `?y2 = λx. x`, and since `refl` has no assumptions, this resolution finishes the proof.

I am not entirely sure what you mean with ‘And why it is not considered in `refl`?’, but I hope that I have answered your questions.

Comment: Thank you Manuel! The only thing I am missing here (and probably because I don't know the unification rules, although I did a serious amount of digging): why not have `?y2` (instead of `?y2 x`) (as you suspected that this will bog me down ;-) )? I would  expect (naively) that `?y2` is replaced with just `x`. I understand your reasoning but `?y2` being a surprise function rather just an faithful using the `x` makes me wonder. Could you please explain how this happened (mechanically, how the program chose this)?

Comment: No I cannot. Higher order unification is a very complicated problem with a very complex solution. I never made a serious attempt to understand how it works in detail. You can perhaps look at Conal Elliott's PhD thesis (http://conal.net/papers/elliott90.pdf), Gerard Huet's original paper ‘A Unification Algorithm for typed Lambda-Calculus’, and perhaps the ML code of Isabelle's matching algorithm (or perhaps the ones used in other, simpler provers like HOL Light)

Comment: I actually realized after your answer that I don't know enough yet about unification :-). Thank you for your help!

Comment: If, like me, you just want to prove theorems, you do not have to understand higher order unification. I more or less know what it does, but I don't know much about the details or how it works. That's good enough for using (and even writing code for) a theorem prover. I would wager that most Isabelle developers do not know how this algorithm works in detail.

Answer (score 2):

Get a more complete answer from an expert, but I give a short, brief answer to your second part.

The great thing about Isabelle is that it provides many different ways to prove a problem.

Your new question is similar to L.Paulson's comment on FOM: you moved the goal post by switching the question to `rule` vs. `simp`:

http://www.cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2015-October/019312.html

Getting a basic understanding of `simp` is actually a much easier goal to pursue, or I wouldn't be adding my reponse here.

## `rule` and natural deduction

The use of `rule` is the use of natural deduction (ND), where most people aren't up to speed on ND. The use of ND requires *understanding ND*, so questions like your first question can lead to a non-simple answer, because anything informative can't be a one-liner answer, especially due to things like schematic variables (which you asked about), resolution, unification, rewriting, etc.

Do a search on natural deduction and you'll find the standard wiki page about it. There are numerous books on natural deduction, though they get swamped in searches on "logic" due to first-order logic books. A popular book is *Logic in Computer Science*, 2nd, by Huth and Ryan.

If you study ND, you'll see that `exI` matches one of the ND rules.

I have yet to take the time to come up to speed on ND, because I keep making progress without having more than a basic understanding of ND.

Sledgehammer, and auto-methods `auto`, `simp`, `blast`, `induct`, `cases`, etc., and Sledgehammer's use of some of those, keep me from finding the time to become good with natural decution.

Answer's like M.Eberl's, though not simple explanations, help me absorb a little here and a little there.

## Simp, I think of it as simple substitution (rewriting)

The mechanics behind `simp` is really simple, compared to natural deduction. You define a formula and prove it:

```
lemma foo [simp]: "left_hand_side = right_hand_side"
```

In the proof of another theorem, when `simp` is invoked in one way or another, or `foo` is unfolded, where there is `left_hand_side`, it's replaced with `right_hand_side`. It's just classic mathematical substitution.

I suppose it could also be "rewriting", but I don't know anything about rewriting, other than they talk about it.

There are lots of details about how and whether one should set things up automatically (to prevent looping), like with `[simp]` or `declare foo_def [simp add]`, but that's just details along the line of normal programming.