# Solve ~(P /\ Q) |- Q -> ~P in Isabelle

Tags: logic, isabelle

~(P /\ Q)  |-  Q -> ~P

I don't know where to start.
Negation confuses me.

I have to solve this in Isabelle (a program), but if someone explains how to solve using natural deduction, it will be enough help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems like a homework exercise you want us to solve for you (it is not the purpose of SO to do that).

Comment: @chris Yes, it's a homework exercise, and what? I tryied to solve, studied, searched, and still could'nt answer, now I need to see how it is solved. It's a programming language question too, so I'm able to ask here.

Comment: Okay, in the meantime I learned that there are two camps regarding homework questions (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) on SO. So just because it is a homework question I probably shouldn't vote to close it (and won't do so in future). However, what applies to every SO question is that the OP should give concrete evidence and/or code in order to show that (and how) she/he tried to solve a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an example that the quality of an SO question is many times determined by an answer, not the question. I kind of give this answer to thank M.Eberl for another useful answer, since I can't make comments.

As to a comment above, that you may be asking a homework question, the comment is valid, but if you're confused by negation, then you're mostly doomed anyway, until you make progress, so even one complete answer wouldn't help you, and here, there's no right answer.

The formula is so basic, except through applying step-by-step rules, it would be hard for anyone to prove that they understand what they're proved, without going through the multitude of tedious steps to do so.

For example:

```
lemma "~(P ∧ Q) ==> Q --> ~P"
  by auto
```

Surely that gets you nothing, if the requirement is that you demonstrate understanding.

I've largely made progress "by the method of absorption over time", and in his answer, M.Eberl gave a significant outline of the basics of natural deduction. My interest in it was to mess around and see if I could absorb a little more.

As to `rule` and `erule`, there is the cheat sheet:

http://www.phil.cmu.edu/~avigad/formal/FormalCheatSheet.pdf

As to the proof of logic by means of Isabelle, Isabelle/HOL is so big and involved, that a little help, once, doesn't get you much, though collectively, it's all important.

## A basic, logic equivalency

I learned long ago the equivalent statement of an implication. It's even in [HOL.thy, line 998](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/5ae2a2e74c93/src/HOL/HOL.thy#l998):

```
lemma disj_not2: "(P | ~Q) = (Q --> P)"
```

From that, it's easy to see, along with DeMorgon's laws (line 993 of HOL.thy), that you stated an equivalency in your question.

Well, of course, not quite, and that's where all the hassle comes in. Rearranging things, based on trivial equivalencies, to finally prove the equivalency. (While also knowing what the notation means, such as that your `|-` will be `==>`. I use ASCII because I don't trust the graphical in browsers.)

M.Eberl mentioned structured proofs. Consider this one:

```
lemma "~(P ∧ Q) ==> Q --> ~P"
proof-
  fix P Q :: bool
  assume "~(P ∧ Q)"
  hence "~P ∨ ~Q" by simp
  hence "~Q ∨ ~P" by metis
  thus "Q --> ~P" by metis
qed
```

What would I deserve in points, for homework? Nothing much. It's actually a testimony that `metis` knows how to use basic first-order logic. Otherwise, how did it know to make the jump from `~Q ∨ ~P` to `Q --> ~P`?

Comment: I found this to be a very helpful answer, from a completely different perspective than the initial homework-asker, the perspective of "I know Lean syntax pretty well, and now I am trying to see how the same basic stuff is handled by Isabelle" ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are talking about Isabelle/HOL, you can use ‘single-step tactics’ like `rule`, `erule`, `assumption` with the basic natural deduction rules. The ones you will probably need for your proposition are:

- introduction rules `notI`, `conjI`, `disjE` `impI`
- elimination rules like `notE`, `conjE`, `disjE`, `impE`
- destruction rules like `mp` (modus ponens), `conjunct1`, `conjunct2`

If you want to find out what a particular rule means, just write e.g. `thm notI` and Isabelle will display the statement of the theorem.

You can set up a goal like

```
lemma "¬(P ∧ Q) ⟹ Q ⟶ ¬P"
```

and then write e.g.

```
apply (rule impI)
```

to apply the introduction rules for implication, which leaves you with the updated goal state

```
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. ¬ (P ∧ Q) ⟹ Q ⟹ ¬ P
```

Now you find the next appropriate rule and apply that one etc. until all subgoals are solved. Then you can write `done` and your proof is complete.

As for `assumption` and `erule`: if you end up with a goal that has some `P` to prove and `P` is already in the assumptions, you can use `apply assumption` to solve it. (`erule` is like `rule` with `assumption` chained directly after it and is often convenient for applying elimination rules)

However, this kind of proof is very tedious to do. A better way would be to do the whole proof in Isar, Isabelle's structured proof language. For an introduction to Isar, you can have a look at chapter 5 of [Concrete Semantics](http://www.concrete-semantics.org/concrete-semantics.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Similar to a JIT compiler, this is a LJEFAATGAA answer (learn just enough from another answer to give an answer).

This is more about what I learned than about what others may learn, which may help others learn; the Isabelle learning curve is quite brutal. I'd think the time has come and gone for the OP's need for help.

- Except for M.Eberl's answer to [*exI and refl behavior explanation needed*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33425599/isabelle-exi-and-refl-behavior-explanation-needed/33430994#33430994), it would still be a mystery to me about why `rule thm` produces specific goal states, for a particular `thm`, and why `rule thm` produces the message *Failed to apply initial proof method*.
- Except for the precise outline given by Chris, with the rules and braces, I wouldn't have been able to fill in the precise details. An example that if a person has the time to learn, it's better for them to be given a partial answer, to make them do a little work, than to give them the complete answer.

## Two main driving points

After a few comments, I show my proof from the outline. It got me the following understanding from having to work out the details, where I talk as if I know I'm right:

1. The use of `apply(rule thm)` is being applied to a combination of the chained facts and the goal statement, where `this`, in the output, displays one or more chained facts.
2. Braces start and end a local context/scope. Variables inside and outside the context/scope work as we would expect them to work, that is, as scope normally works in programming languages. So if I state `fix P Q :: bool` at the beginning of a proof, then state `fix Q :: bool` in a sub-context, the `Q` in the sub-context refers to a different variable than the parent-context `Q`.

Having properly credited Chris, I insert his outline here, so it can easily be compared to the Isar source:

```
1. ~(P & Q) premise
2. { Q       assumption
3.   { P     assumption
4.     P & Q and-introduction 3, 2
5.     _|_   negation-elimination 1, 4 }
6.   ~P      negation-introduction 3-5 }
7. Q -> ~P   implication-introduction 2-6
```

The source:

```
lemma "~(P & Q) ==> Q --> ~P"
proof-
  fix P Q :: bool
  assume a1: "~(P & Q)"
  { 
    assume a2: "Q"
    { 
      assume a3: "P"
      have a4: "P & Q" 
        apply(rule conjI) apply(rule a3) by(rule a2)
      (* NOTE: have to set 'notE' up right. Next 'hence False' doesn't do it. *)
      (* hence False apply(rule) by(metis a1) *)
      (* 'rule' applies the default of 'conjI', because there is the fact
         'this: P & Q', which comes from 'hence'; 'rule notE' gives an error.*)
      from a1 a4
      have False (* From 'this' and 'goal': ~(P & Q) ⟹ P & Q ==> False *)
        by(rule notE) (* notE: ~P ==> P ==> R *)
    }
    hence "~P" 
      apply(rule notI) by(assumption)
  }
  thus "Q --> ~P" 
    apply(rule impI) by(assumption)
qed
```

## Understanding scope better

Thinking was being required at my statement `have False`. I wasn't setting things up right for `notE`. Just to see if I was on the right track, I would execute `sledgehammer`, but it wasn't able to prove `False` within that context.

It was because I was on auto-pilot, and was using `fix Q :: bool` and `fix P :: bool` in the two local contexts. I took them out and `sledgehammer` easily found proofs.

That's an example of a person knowing some logic, but not knowing how to implement the logic correctly in the languages Isabelle/HOL and Isabelle/Isar.

Next, I had to learn how to set up things correctly for `apply(rule notE)`.

## Belaboring a point

Part of my understanding about the above source comes from seeing the phrase *chained facts* in [isar-ref.pdf](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2015/dist/Isabelle2015/doc/isar-ref.pdf). Minor exposure to the natural deduction rules, along with M.Eberl's explanation about unification, instantiation, and resolution finally helped make sense of what happens in the output panel.

Above, I have `hence False` commented out, and then use `have False`. Fortunately, in Isabelle, there are multiple ways to do things, but the goal was to apply `notE`. Even with that, there are different Isar keywords that can be used to set things up.

Anyway, seeing how chained facts are used with `rule` was a light-bulb moment. I guess here's effectively what's involved at the statement `have False`, as it relates to `notE`:

```
term "~P ==> P ==> R" (* notE: line 376 of HOL.thy *)

lemma "~(P & Q) ⟹ P & Q ==> False"
  by(rule notE)
```

If I had an account, I would upvote the question to get rid of that -1.

Thanks to Chris for giving the precise outline.

Answer (score 0):

Since you explicitly mentioned natural deduction. In a specific flavour of natural deduction -- where lines are numbered and the scope of assumptions is explicitly marked by boxes (denoted by curly braces below) -- one way of proving your statement is the following:

```
1. ~(P & Q) premise
2. { Q       assumption
3.   { P     assumption
4.     P & Q and-introduction 3, 2
5.     _|_   negation-elimination 1, 4 }
6.   ~P      negation-introduction 3-5 }
7. Q -> ~P   implication-introduction 2-6
```

Actually, since your goal is to prove an implication, you only have one choice at the start, namely implication introduction.

It would be a good exercise to translate the above proof as faithfully as possible into a structured Isar proof (e.g., using what is called "raw proof blocks" and incidentally also denoted by curly braces in Isabelle).